# Prime numbers and assertions

Tags: solution-verification, prime-numbers

> Suppose that $\displaystyle\frac{x}{3}, \frac{y}{3}, \frac{x+y}{3}$
> are distinct primes. Check whether following assertions hold in
> general:
>
> 1. $\displaystyle xy$ is a prime number.
> 2. $\displaystyle \frac{x^2+y^2}{9}$ is a prime number.
> 3. $\displaystyle \frac{x-y}{3}$ is a prime number.

It turns out that

$$x = 3p_x, y = 3p_y, x+y = 3(p_x+p_y)$$

Where $p_x\neq p_y\neq p_z$ are primes. Therefore,

$$xy = 3p_1\times 3p_2 = 9p_1\times p_2\equiv 0\pmod{9}\tag{1}$$

$$\frac{x^2+y^2}{9} = p^2_x+p^2_y\tag{2}$$

$$\frac{x-y}{3} = p_x-p_y\tag{3}$$

Now since the only even prime is $2$, if $p_x, p_y\neq 2$, then $p_x + p_y$ is even, so for $p_x+p_y$ to be prime, we require that $p_x = 2$ or $p_y = 2$.

Comment: What's the question?  I agree with you that one of $\frac x3$ and $\frac y3$ must be $2$.  After all, the sum of two odd primes is even.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Now if $p_x = 11$ and $p_y = 2$, then $p_x-p_y = 11-2 = 9$ which is non-prime, i.e condition $(3)$ is not true in general. It's also obvious that $(1)$ isn't either. What about $(2)$? That's probably not true as well.

Comment: As you say, just work examples.  There are lots of twin prime pairs so just test.

Comment: Sure. For disproving $(2)$, now take $p_x = 19$ and $p_y = 2$ so that $p^2_x+p^2_y = 19^2 + 2^2  = 365$ which is non-prime. However, the problem is that question demands $p_x+p_y$ is a prime, so this instance is invalid.

Comment: So try $(11,13)$ as the twin prime pair.

Comment: You cannot, because one of them is $2$.

Comment: Yes, that's why I use twin primes.  If $(p,p+2)$ are both primes then you can take $x=6, y=3p$.

Comment: I think I found the counter-example: take $p_x = 29$ and $p_y = 2$ so that $p^2_x + p^2_y = 845$ which is non-prime, and $p_x + p_y = 31$ is a prime as desired.

Comment: It is enough to find ONE counterexample for every of the three cases to refute all the claims.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarize the discussion in the comments:

Let $p_x=\frac x3$, $p_y=\frac y3$.

If both $p_x,p_y$ are odd then $p_x+p_y$ is even, hence not prime.  Thus one of them equals $2$.  Without loss of generality, let's say $p_x=2$ so $x=6$.

For that reason, any twin prime pair gives us a good $(x,y)$.  Indeed, if $(p, p+2)$ are both prime, then taking $x=6,y=3p$ works and the above discussion shows that all good pairs arise this way (up to switching $x,y$).

Now for the questions:

1. is clearly false since $3\,|\,xy$ (and $3\neq xy$).
2. False.  Take the twin pair $(11,13)$.  Thus we get $x=6, y=33$.  With that choice we remark that $\frac {x^2+y^2}9=125$ which is not prime.
3. False.  Same counterexample.  $\frac {33-6}3=9$ which is not prime.